# How do I hide 'Div' in html using jquery on a button click event where the button is in the same Div

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, html

on the button click of "ajaxSearchValues" I have to hide "divFilters"

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")
    <div id="divFilters" >
       WR No
       @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) Model.p_NO, New With {.class = "span2"})
       <div style="float: right;">
         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" id="ajaxSearchValues" />
       </div>
    </div>
End Using
```

My Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#ajaxSearchValues').click(function () {                
    $('#divFilters').hide()                           
  });
});
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Why is your button a `submit`?

Comment: submit because i do other functions using the button. The button is in the same Div("divFilters") when i hit the button it works fine(hides) untill the page loads once the page is completely loaded it shows .

Comment: Well of course it does. Your rendering a new view! If you want to do a normal submit and return the view with the div hidden then you would need to post back some additional value indicating the state. Otherwise use ajax to submit, which stays on the same page